# NavigationView does not show PaneHeader when IsPaneToggleButtonVisible is false

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml, navigationview

I have an issue with the NavigationView control in my UWP app. When I set the *IsPaneToggleButtonVisible* to false, my PaneHeader collapses too. Offically this bug was [solved](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/1005), am I doing something wrong?

```
<NavigationView PaneDisplayMode="Left" IsPaneToggleButtonVisible="False" IsBackButtonVisible="Collapsed" OpenPaneLength="200" IsSettingsVisible="False" Height="923">
                            <NavigationView.PaneHeader>
                                <Image x:Name="Header" Source="/Assets/Header.png" Stretch="UniformToFill" Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="216" Height="53"/>
                            </NavigationView.PaneHeader>
<NavigationView/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this [thread](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/1005), it mentions

> This issue was addressed in #1083, which has now been successfully
>   released as Microsoft.UI.Xaml v2.2.190731001-prerelease.

This means the bug has solved in the Windows UI Library version of NavigationView, so if you want to show your PaneHeader, you need to install the [Microsoft.UI.Xaml nuget package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/toolkits/winui/getting-started) and then add `<XamlControlsResources xmlns="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls"/>` to your Application.Resources.

.App.xaml:

```
<Application>
    <Application.Resources>
        <XamlControlsResources xmlns="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls" /> 
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

.MainPage.xaml:

```
<Page
    ......
    xmlns:muxc="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls"
    >

    <Grid>
        <muxc:NavigationView PaneDisplayMode="Left" IsPaneToggleButtonVisible="False" IsBackButtonVisible="Collapsed" OpenPaneLength="200" IsSettingsVisible="False" Height="923">
            <muxc:NavigationView.PaneHeader>
                <Image x:Name="Header" Source="Assets/StoreLogo.png" Stretch="UniformToFill" Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="53" Height="53"/>
            </muxc:NavigationView.PaneHeader>
        </muxc:NavigationView>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```